# Return a value from a loop in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a game in RoR.  The game breaks down like this.  There are Levels, Levels have Missions and Missions have Gameplays (your attempt to complete the mission).

To pass a level you just need to complete 1 mission.  So in my Level model, I am trying to write  method to determine if a user has passed the level and can't seem to get it.  I need to return true if the gamplay score is > the score required to pass the mission.

This is where I'm at.  How can I exit the loop and return true if I find a Gameplay with a score > the mission score?

```
  def user_has_passed(user)
    self.missions.each do |mi|
      plays = Gameplay.where(:user_id => user.id, :mission_id => mi.id)
      #code here, if a play.score > mi.score return true, else return false
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you add one more part to the where call?

```
  good_plays = Gameplay.where(:user_id => user.id, :mission_id => mi.id).where("score > ?", mi.score)
```

And with this if you get any plays (good.plays.size > 0) you are good

Or with your query, you need one more loop

```
  plays.each do |play|
    return true if play.score > mi.score
  end
```

Comment: yeah, been trying things very similar but seem to always get false, has to be something stupid on my end

Comment: got it, was missing an "each" at the end of my self.missions - your good_plays line worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
return play.score > mi.score
```

That should handle it succinctly. More verbosely:

```
return play.score > mi.score ? true : false
```

or

```
if play.score > mi.score
  return true
else
  return false
end
```

Note that the `return` is not strictly necessary as the last expression evaluated is what your method returns, but it helps to be explicit -- at least at first.

Comment: that's what I thought, but I only have a plays collect, not a single play, when I try to loop through plays it seems to always return false, see my edit

Answer (score 2):

You should try `any?`

`plays.any? { |play| play.score > mi.score }`